# Can't use Bitmap in Console Application

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get the Bitmap class to work properly.
I've googled a ton, and the same answer is everywhere -> "Add reference to System.Drawing", which I've done(I think).

I've added the reference via **Project** -> **Add COM reference** -> **Browse** and then select "Sytem.drawing.visualstudio.dll"
The answers on Google refer to select "Add reference", but I only have "Add Project reference", "Add COM reference" and "Add Shared Project Reference".

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap myBit = new Bitmap("url"); //ERROR
        }
```

Here I get the error: **"CS1069: Bitmap could not be found in the namespace "Sytem.Drawing"**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: All the tutorials you'll find assume you use a different project template.  It matters.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as-is, because you haven't provided enough information about your programming environment. Handling of assembly references has varied over the years and different versions of Visual Studio, and the latest iteration of Visual Studio has once again made a significant change, at least for .NET 5 projects. Please edit your question and tell us _exactly_ what version of VS you're using (see the "About" box for the version #), and _exactly_ what type and version of project you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've added the reference via Project -> Add COM reference -> Browse and then select "Sytem.drawing.visualstudio.dll"

You shouldn't be adding a `COM` reference and that's not the correct library to add. See below to add the correct reference to use the `System.Drawing` namespace that has `Bitmap` class.

1. Right click on `References` under your project.
2. Select `Add Reference`.
3. Click on `Assemblies`.
4. In the top right -> `Search` -> `system.draw` etc...
5. A few items should show, select `System.Drawing` (mine was 4.0.0.0) make sure it's checked.
6. Click `OK`.

You should now see under `References` under your project the namespace.

[image]